# What is meant by 'I couldn't wait to leave'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is meant by **"I couldn't wait to leave"** in the following dialogue:

- One day a traveller was walking along a road on a journey from one
  village to another. He noticed a farmer working in a field of crops
  beside the road.
- The traveller stopped for a moment, greeted the farmer, and said, ‘I’ve just been to the village in the mountains, and I am now on my way to the village in the valley. Have you been there? Can you tell me what that village is like?’
- ‘How did you find the village in the mountains?’ asked the farmer.
- ‘It was terrible,’ replied the traveller. ‘***I couldn’t wait to leave.*** The people were cold and unwelcoming to me.

*Kindly, can somebody rephrase it (i.e. I couldn't wait to leave) in a more clear way?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "**[couldn't wait](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+wait)**" refers to *impatience* and *eagerness*. The traveler is saying he was impatient and eager to leave so he could get away from the "cold and unwelcoming" people.